# SQL - Getting the sum of times between multiple ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, logic, boolean-logic

[image]

The above picture represents something I've been trying to accomplish in MSSQL.

It's a schedule with multiple time ranges, A to B it's overtime, B to C regular work in the morning, C to D lunch time, D to E regular work in the afternoon and E to F, overtime too.

For the sake of simplicity, I've declared manually A,B,C,D,E and F to fixed values. In reality these will be fed from another table, but it's not relevant for this problem.

The vertical arrows, represent the clocking in/out time.

So, let's say IN it's 8am and OUT it's 7pm.

How can I retrieve the following?

- Work: 8h
- Lunch: 1h
- Overtime: 2h

Without using a mess of **IF**'s and knowing that IN could be in the middle of B and C for example.

Someone clocking in at 11am and clocking out at 7pm would now have work=6h, lunch=1h, overtime=1h.

Thank you.

As an example, my current spaghetti code, surely there's a more elegant (and cleaner) way to accomplish this.

```
declare @clockIn time = '08:00'
declare @clockOut time = '19:00'

declare @a time= '00:00'
...all possible limits defined here...
declare @f time= '23:59'

tests using C to D only:

-- in block
IF(@clockIn >= @c
   AND @clockOut <= @d)
    BEGIN
        SET @at = @at + ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, @clockIn, @clockOut));
    END;
-- outside block
IF(@clockIn < @c
   AND @clockOut > @d)
    BEGIN
        SET @at = @at + ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, @c, @d));
    END;
-- cIn in block, cOut outside
IF(@clockIn >= @c
   AND @clockOut > @d)
    BEGIN
        SET @at = @at + ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, @clockIn, @d));
    END;
-- cIn outside, cIn inside
IF(@clockIn < @c
   AND @clockOut <= @d)
    BEGIN
        SET @at = @at + ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, @c, @clockOut));
    END
select @ax as overtime,@at as work,@ai as lunch
```

Comment: Well, you have to build the business logic in one way or another. Personally I'd try to structure it in a neat-as-possible case expression (with a cross join between the table containing hours worked and the table with the regular times) while leaving comments about the business logic for anyone who comes across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way you can do this without building the if-then logic in somehow, so it's a matter of how you do it. I think the simplest (and perhaps most readable) way of doing this is to just use a case expression for each time required, perhaps leaving some comments about the logic behind it so anyone who comes across it can more easily understand how it works.

For example, something like this should be simple enough without being too much of a mess (IMO):

```
DECLARE @Clock TABLE (Clockin TIME NOT NULL, Clockout TIME NOT NULL);
INSERT @Clock VALUES ('12:30', '19:00');

DECLARE @Times TABLE (WorkStart TIME NOT NULL, LunchStart TIME NOT NULL, LunchEnd TIME NOT NULL, WorkEnd TIME NOT NULL);
INSERT @Times VALUES ('09:00', '12:00', '13:00', '18:00');

SELECT 
    OverTime = 
        (CASE -- Overtime hours in the morning.
            WHEN C.Clockin < T.WorkStart -- Clocked in before official work start.
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, C.Clockin, CASE WHEN C.Clockout > T.WorkStart THEN T.WorkStart ELSE C.Clockout END) 
            ELSE 0 
        END + 
        CASE -- Overtime hours in the evening.
            WHEN C.Clockout > T.WorkEnd -- Clocked out after official work end.
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CASE WHEN C.Clockin > T.WorkEnd THEN C.Clockin ELSE T.WorkEnd END, C.Clockout) 
            ELSE 0 
        END) / 60.0,
    Work =
        (CASE -- Work hours for the morning.
            WHEN C.Clockout > T.WorkStart AND C.Clockin < T.LunchStart -- Clocked out after official work start and clocked in before official lunch start.
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CASE WHEN C.Clockin < T.WorkStart THEN T.WorkStart ELSE C.Clockin END, CASE WHEN C.Clockout < T.LunchStart THEN C.Clockout ELSE T.LunchStart END) 
            ELSE 0
        END + 
        CASE -- Work hours for the afternoon.
            WHEN C.Clockin < T.WorkEnd AND C.Clockout > T.LunchEnd -- Clocked out after official lunch end and clocked in before official work end.
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CASE WHEN C.Clockin < T.LunchEnd THEN T.LunchEnd ELSE C.Clockin END, CASE WHEN C.Clockout < T.WorkEnd THEN C.Clockout ELSE T.WorkEnd END) 
            ELSE 0
        END) / 60.0,
    Lunch =
        CASE -- Lunch hours.
            WHEN C.Clockin < T.LunchEnd AND C.Clockout > T.LunchStart -- Clocked in before official lunch end and clocked out after official lunch start.
            THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CASE WHEN C.Clockin > T.LunchStart THEN C.Clockin ELSE T.LunchStart END, CASE WHEN C.Clockout < T.LunchEnd THEN C.Clockout ELSE T.LunchEnd END) 
            ELSE 0
        END / 60.0
FROM @Clock AS C
CROSS JOIN @Times AS T;
```